# Возможна ли инициализация map на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c++, stl, map

Могу ли я, скажем, создать в классе константный статический map и проинициализировать его необходимыми знаечниями на этапе компиляции? Если это возможно, то как?

Comment: А `map` разве не выделяет память во время выполнения?

Comment: В `std::map` отсутствуют `constexpr` конструкторы, но с кастомной реализацией (хотя бы просто через отсортированный массив) - запросто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На всякий случай - если именно проинициалзировать во время компиляции, т.е. чтобы вся структура еще до работы программы уже находилась в памяти со всей настроенной внутренней структурой etc etc, то нет.

Но если тут терминологическая путаница, и вы просто хотите указать при компиляции, какие значения в нем должны быть при выполнении программы, т.е. чтоб их внес конструктор - тогда да.

```
struct Test
{
    static const map<int,int> m;
};

const map<int,int> Test::m = {{1,2},{4,18},{2,15}};

int main()
{
    for(auto [a,b]: Test::m) cout << a << "  " << b << endl;
}
```

Вы хотите чего-то такого?

С точки зрения пользователя/программиста, если вы не вносите таким образом миллионы значений - то разницы, внесли вы их при компиляции или при первом обращении, по большому счету нет - какие-то микросекунды.

Comment: *"разницы, внесли вы их при компиляции или при первом обращении, по большому счету нет"* - а потом люди отстреливают себе ноги и другие конечности из-за Static (un) Initialization Order Fiasco.

Comment: По сути, это просто часть кода, которая выполняется до main (и таким образом *можно* выполнить код произвольной сложности). Но как правильно указал @user7860670, в случае крестового кода это путь в ад

Comment: @avp Отстрелить себе ногу можно и на более ровной поверхности :) Так и `int i = 5` в глобальной области писать страшно получается :) Ах, да, применение статических переменных тоже надо запретить, не только в классах, но и в функциях...

Comment: По крйней мере пока, к счастью, нет, не страшно. Инициализация памяти перед вызовом main осуществляется в несколько этапов. Обычно 1) memset(bss, 0, bssize); 2) memcpy(data, const_section, size_consts); 3) вызов всех функций инициализации в цикле (вот тут порядок не определен, зависит от того в каком порядке они попали линкеру)

Comment: @avp Тогда и в таком вот варианте, где нет никаких перекрестных ссылок, тоже не страшно...

Comment: @Harry, в студенческих поделках вы легко можете все сделать работоспособным. В развивающемся проекте подобные штуки могут вызывать совершенно неопределенное поведение и муки с отладкой, когда вы толком даже не понимаете что где и когда сломалось. Впрочем, умные люди уже давно все про это [сказали](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus)

Comment: @avp Теперь точно вижу, что недаром у меня идеосинкразия на Linux :) Предпочитаю разговаривать с Бьярне...